# Share non-parcelable item between App and service

Tags: java, android, service, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm looking for one way to share a non-parcelable item from my application and my current Service. This is the situation:

I have a Service to store all the media data from a camera application, photos, videos etc. The mission of this service is continue saving the media when the user go to background. When I did this in a first instance, I had a lot of SIGSEGV errors:

```
08-22 10:15:49.377 15784-15818/com.bq.camerabq A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8c3f4000 in tid 15818 (CameraModuleBac)
```

This was because the Image item that I recover from my imageReaders are not parceable, I fix this saving the Bytebuffers from the image instead of the whole image item.

But, now I'm getting the same problem with DNG captures, because from my imageReader I got a CaptureResult item that I need to use to create a `DngCreator` item to write the dng image.

CaptureResults and DngCreators are not parcelables or Serializables, so I don't find a way to save my data from the application to recover it in the service if I'm in background.

I have tried to copy the reference when calling the Service and it didn't worked. Also I saw in other posts as [Object Sharing Between Activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219787/object-sharing-between-activities-in-android) and [Object Sharing Between Activities in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219787/object-sharing-between-activities-in-android) that I can save the item in a static reference in my application context to be able to recover it in different activities. So finally I tried this:

```
public class DngManager extends Application {
    public static DngManager sDngManagerInstance;
    protected Hashtable<String, CaptureResult> dngCaptureResults;
    private static String DNG_KEY_PREFIX = "dngResult_";

    public DngManager(){
        super();
        createDNGCaptureResults();
    }

    public void createDNGCaptureResults() {
        dngCaptureResults = new Hashtable<String, CaptureResult>();
    }

    public boolean addDNGCaptureResultToSharedMem(long dateKey, CaptureResult value) {
        dngCaptureResults.put(DNG_KEY_PREFIX + dateKey, value);
        return true;
    }

    public CaptureResult getFromDNGCaptureResults(long dateKey) {
        return dngCaptureResults.get(DNG_KEY_PREFIX + dateKey);
    }

    private boolean containsDNGCaptureResults(long dateKey) {
        return  dngCaptureResults.containsKey(DNG_KEY_PREFIX + dateKey);
    }

    public void clearDNGCaptureResults(long dateKey) {
        String partKey = String.valueOf(dateKey);
        Enumeration<String> e2 = dngCaptureResults.keys();
        while (e2.hasMoreElements()) {
            String i = (String) e2.nextElement();
            if (i.contains(partKey))
                dngCaptureResults.remove(i);
        }
    }

    public static DngManager getInstance(){
        if (sDngManagerInstance == null){
            sDngManagerInstance = new DngManager();
        }
        return sDngManagerInstance;
    }
}
```

And later I recover it in my service:

```
 CaptureResult dngResult = ((DngManager)getApplication()).getFromDNGCaptureResults(mDngPicture.getDateTaken());
            if (dngResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            DngCreator dngCreator = new DngCreator(mCameraCharacteristics, dngResult);
            path = Storage.generateFilepath(title, "dng");
            file = new File(Uri.decode(path));
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "[DngSaveTask|run] WriteByteBuffer: Height " + mDngPicture.getSize().getHeight() + " Width " + mDngPicture.getSize().getWidth());
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                dngCreator.writeByteBuffer(os, mDngPicture.getSize(), mDngPicture.getDngByteBuffer(), 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "[DngSaveTask|run] " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        dngCreator.close();
        Log.e(TAG, "[DngSaveTask|run] Cleaning Result from shared memory");
        DngManager.getInstance().clearDNGCaptureResults(mDngPicture.getDateTaken());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

Anyway, it still giving me back a SIGSEGV error. What else can I try?